# How to pop up a window using just the git bash command? [Windows 10]

Tags: git, terminal, windows-10, git-bash, display

Does anybody know which command should I use for git bash terminal to pop up a window?

Let's say I changed my directory to Documents from ~ and I just want a single command that will help me load up the Documents folder visuals in the screen without having me to click the mouse.

Also I wonder which git bash command lets the windows 10 to return all the running process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you want to open bash command you can use this command in CMD or create shortcut form this command:

```
%ComSpec% /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i"
```

> `%ComSpec%` is one of the environment variables used in DOS, OS/2 and Windows, which normally points to the command line interpreter, which is by default **`CMD.EXE`**

Comment: so after that what will be the command in sequence to enter to pop up the Documents window?

Comment: in the bash type: `cd ~/Documents`

Comment: It doesn't pop up the window but just changes the directory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably

```
explorer .
```

It will open the windows file explorer in the current directory.
You can't however use

```
explorer /home
```

As explorer expects only windows-style paths.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my `.bashrc` which reads the argument passed in, and converts it to a Windows style path, and uses explorer to open it.

```
function open() {
    pth=$(realpath "$1")
    pth=$(echo $pth | sed -e 's/^\///' -e 's/\//\\/g' -e 's/^./\0:/')
    explorer "$pth"
}
```

then I run `open .` or `open ~/some/path`

(Note: you will have to open a new terminal window or `source ~/.bashrc` before the command is usable)